# Prove: if $i \in \text{Supp } \sigma \Rightarrow \sigma(i)\in \text{Supp } \sigma$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> Let $\text{Supp }  \sigma =\{k\in\{1,2,...,n\}:\sigma(k)\neq k\}$, Prove:  if $i \in \text{Supp }  \sigma \Rightarrow \sigma(i)\in \text{Supp } \sigma$

Let assume that $\sigma(i)\not{\in} \text{Supp } \sigma$ therefore by definition $\sigma(\sigma(i))=\sigma(i)$, but $S_{n}$ in a group, so there is $\sigma^{-1}\in S_{n}$ such that $\sigma\cdot \sigma^{-1}=\sigma^{-1}\cdot \sigma=id$, so if we composite $\sigma^{-1}$ we get $\sigma^{-1}\cdot\sigma\cdot\sigma(i)=\sigma^{-1}\cdot\sigma(i)\rightarrow \sigma(i)=i$ in contradiction.

Comment: If you define $\operatorname{Supp} \sigma$ as the complement of $\operatorname{Fix} \sigma$ then it  is obvious that $i \in \operatorname{Fix} \sigma \iff\sigma(i) \in \operatorname{Fix} \sigma$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems correct to me. But note that where you've written $\sigma^{-1}\cdot\sigma\cdot\sigma(i)$, this is the group element $\sigma^{-1}\cdot\sigma$ applied to $\sigma(i)$, which is an element of the underlying set. So it should be written $\sigma^{-1}\cdot\sigma(\sigma(i))$. (And similarly your $\sigma^{-1}\cdot\sigma(i)$ should be $\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(i))$.

Edit: what I've written after the "but" above is of course not right, what you have is perfectly correct. (Though the way I've written it I think makes the argument slightly clearer to me at least.)